# Qt: where is the best "Path" to save SQLite database of a Qt-creator application?

Tags: c++, qt, sqlite, qt-creator

Currently, I am hard coding the path of my SQLite database for development and debugging reasons as follow:

```
QString path = "/Users/user/Documents/workspace/application/";
db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QSQLITE");
db.setDatabaseName(path+"dbFile");
db.open()
```

But, for future "release" version, I need the application to create, save and access the database in user's machine. So, what is the best location to save the database of a Qt-creator application? and how can I do that ?!

Comment: Hmm, try to move `database` file into QtCreator's project under resources ...

Comment: You mean create a resources folder inside the project's main folder ? ... @KernelPanic

Comment: It depends what you mean by best.  Do you want the db to be able to be changed easily?  Do you not want to be able to change it easily?  Do you want security on it?

Comment: I want it to be embedded within the application so that the "normal" user can start working on the application without having to worry about where the database is located ... Now, if a user installed the application and attempt to run it, the application will crash as her/his machine doesn't have the path I already set  ... security is not a motive (yet) as much as easy accessibility and machine-independently ... @NathanOliver

Comment: For Windows: under "APPDATA\your_product_name\data_file_name"  where the path to APPDATA is found by `SHGetFolderPath` https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762181(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Btw, thanks for pointing out the need to clarify the meaning of "best" ...  myself, I didn't though of what I meant (exactly) by this word until you asked .. you are correct, it is vague  ... @NathanOliver

Comment: I am working on mac, but I will have a look at the link , thanks ... @RichardCritten

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First of all Qt is cross-platform lib and try to use it full capabilities. 
In short:

1. Use [Standard Paths](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstandardpaths.html).
2. Also don`t forget to check writable ability with [writableLocation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstandardpaths.html#writableLocation) or [QFileInfo](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfileinfo.html#isWritable).
3. About place: just give opportunity to user chose. I preferred to store all data in application folder, for easy maintenance. But typically application store all configurations in user directories, it somehow "secure" solution.

Comment: Thank you .. that it precisely what I am looking for.